# Traffic is not routing through Watchguard branch office vpn to Amazon aws VPN

Tags: amazon-vpc, watchguard

Following [this guide](http://customers.watchguard.com/articles/Article/Configure-a-VPN-between-an-XTM-device-and-an-Amazon-Web-Service-AWS-network), I have successfully (I think) created a connection between my Watchguard physical VPN and an Amazon-VPC with a VPN attached to it but I cannot ping my EC-2.

Amazon is setup as follows:

My VPC has a VPN with a customer gateway(75.75.x.x, my office), and a virtual gateway. The VPC also has a private subnet of (192.168.5.0/24) and an ec-2 in that subnet (192.168.5.40). My ACL's are set to allow all traffic in and out. My security group is set to allow all traffic in and out, as well as ICMP.

```
My Route table is set up as:

Destination: 192.168.5.0/24 
Target: local 
Status: Active 
Propagated: No

Destination: 192.168.x.0/24  (x = 0-4)
Target: Virtual Gateway 
Status: Active 
Propagated: Yes

My static routes on the amazon vpn are: 
192.168.0.0/24 
192.168.1.0/24 
192.168.2.0/24 
192.168.4.0/24. 
(These are the subnets in my office.)
```

Edit*
In order to keep the connection alive I had to tell phase 1 to re-connect every hour and turn off NAT. Now I am getting consistent traffic flowing in, but not out to Amazon from my watchguard. I have made a static hop from 192.168.5.0/24 to the virtual Private gateway, per Amazons suggestion on my watchguard device.

[image: Diagram image]

Comment: Could you do an ASCII network diagram?

Comment: @mzhaase Yes I can I'll post one soon

Comment: @mzhaase Diagram added

Comment: Have you added your local subnet to the aws security groups?